# Inequality related to a bijection $x\mapsto |x|^{-2}x$

Tags: inequality, inner-products, absolute-value

Let $x,x'\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with usual norm.
\begin{equation}
\frac{|x-x'|}{(1+|x|)(1+|x'|)} \leq \left|\frac{x}{|x|^2}-\frac{x'}{|x'|^2}\right|
\end{equation}
I have read this inequality, however, fail to prove. I appreciate if one can demonstrate how it follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\left(\frac{|x-x'|}{(1+|x|)(1+|x'|)}\right)^2 \leq \left|\frac{1}{|x|^2}x-\frac{1}{|x'|^2}x'\right|^2$$ or
$$\frac{|x|^2+|x'|^2-2xx'}{(1+|x|)^2(1+|x'|)^2}\leq\frac{1}{|x|^2}+\frac{1}{|x'|^2}-\frac{2}{|x|^2|x'|^2}xx'$$ or
$$(1+|x|)^2(1+|x'|)^2\geq|x|^2|x'|^2,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x}{|x|^2}-\frac{y}{|y|^2}\right|^2&=\frac{1}{|x|^2}+\frac{1}{|y|^2}-2\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^2|y|^2}\\
&=\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2-2x\cdot y}{|x|^2|y|^2}\\
&=\frac{|x-y|^2}{|x|^2|y|^2}\\
&\ge\frac{|x-y|^2}{(1+|x|)^2(1+|y|)^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Chrystomath.Second last line, correct?